# Alternate location for PostgreSQL configuration files

Tags: postgresql

In the documentation for [postgresql.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-file-locations.html), it implies that they envisage a scenario where one might want to store the configuration files in a non-default location (i.e. not inside the data directory).  This is done by passing the location of the config files when starting up the server as `postgres -D /path/to/config/directory`, and having the actual data directory as the value of `data_directory` in `postgresql.conf`.

How are you supposed to set up a new cluster with this separation of configuration files and data?  I would have assumed that there would be a flag to `initdb`, but this is not the case.  Do they just expect you to create the cluster as per usual, and then move the files `postgresql.conf`, `pg_hba.conf` and `pg_ident.conf` by hand?  Any other files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you move them manually where you want them.